# Is there a way to view statistics about total enemies or animals killed?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

While playing Assassin's Creed 3, you occasionally see notices like "you are in the top 50% of players in animals killed."

Is this information accessible outside of these occasional notices? Or are we only presented with bragging material as the game sees fit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

While in game (in single-player while in the Animus), go to the pause menu and open the **Animus Training Center**.

There you can see your personal statistics in the **Stats** menu or see how your stats fare against your friends or the world in the **Leaderboards** menu.

[image: Animus Training Center]

Another option is to log on to the [Assassin's Network](https://assassinsnetwork.ubi.com/) where you can keep track of your Assassin's Creed progression across all titles, participate in the community by forming clans, and fighting in events for great prizes.